# How to plot a time-series to study frequency of items?

Tags: python, time-series, seaborn

I would need to plot through time same values to see how frequency changes. In particular posts generated from different users through time. I have a dataset like the following:

```
       GENDER          POST  DATE  COUNTER
0      men    (post 103)     36        43
1      men    (post 109)     38        2
2      men    (post 116)     41        12
3      men    (post 119)     42        32
4      men    (post 124)     44        2
..       ...           ...   ...      ...
82   women     (post 83)     29        34
83   women     (post 86)     30        2
84   women     (post 86)     65        9
85   women     (post 91)     32        5
86   women     (post 99)     35        5
```

where DATE is numerical (sequential numbers rather than date format)
What I initially thought was to select the columns I am interested in, by using seaborn:

```
from  matplotlib import pyplot
import seaborn

fg = seaborn.FacetGrid(data=df_, hue='GENDER', aspect=1.61)
fg.map(pyplot.scatter, 'DATE', 'COUNTER').add_legend()
```

but in order to have something like the plot shown in the picture below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cawyI.jpg

I think I should consider a time series in order to track posts through time. 
On the x-axis of each plot there would be date (`DATE`) and on y-axis the post's frequency (`COUNTER`).

The file csv that I am considering for this analysis includes the following columns:

```
file = '...'

with open(file, newline='') as csvfile:
    df = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
    for row in df:
         print(' '.join(row)) 
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=';') # or your sep in file
df.columns = [' ', 'GENDER', 'POST', 'DATE', 'COUNTER',' ']
```

Thank you so much for your time and for helping me.

Update:

```
        GENDER  POST DATE COUNTER
0       (man 8) (post 4) 0  0   NaN
1       (woman 13)  (post 1) 2  0   NaN
2       (man 14)    (post 7) 2  2   NaN
3       (man 8) (post 4) 4  1 NaN
4       (woman 19)  (post 12) 4 1   NaN
```

Comment: How many unique posts do you have? Your plot might get a little convoluted if there's many, especially if you're using the `gender` hue

Comment: Also, is there only one row per `post`-`gender`-`date` combination?

Comment: I have about 100 hundred posts, but I would like to study a few of them as otherwise it would be difficult to plot them and also to analyse them.

Comment: and `counter` (the frequency of the post in that date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's filter your dataframe so you only have a handful of posts:

```
import seaborn as sns

post_list = ['(post 103)','(post 109)','(post 116)']
df2 = df[df.POST.isin(post_list)]
```

Then, something like this should do:

```
for post in df2.POST.unique():
    sns.lineplot(x='DATE',y='COUNTER', hue='GENDER', data=df2[df2.POST==post])
plt.show()
```

If you don't care about confidence intervals you can add `ci=None` to the `sns` call, which will make the code run faster.

Comment: thank you so much Juan C. How can I recall these posts from the csv file? I got the following output from the first code: `Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ , GENDER, POST, DATE, COUNTER,  ]
Index: []`

Comment: what do you get when you run `df.head()` ? is it properly loading?

Comment: Please see above the output after running `df.head()`. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: As you can see there, it isn't properly loading. Do you know what might be causing that? Is only gender failing? You might need to parse that dataframe a bit

Comment: what do you mean with only gender failing? How can I parse the data frame? sorry but how you can understand I am not completely familiar with python. `NaN` value probably comes from `df.columns = [' ', 'GENDER', 'POST', 'DATE', 'COUNTER',' ']`

Comment: There are spaces in columns names, see this answer for strip your dataset https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60423879/how-to-convert-a-csv-file-into-a-data-frame/60424229#60424229